# Google Map V3: Loading Markers using AJAX+ASP/PHP and Reload on Ruquest or Event

Tags: ajax, google-maps-api-3

Hi I've searched so many things and found many contents but didn't found what I required actually.

I can loading all markers but unable to Refresh it or Reload it please help me out here's the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(24.86802, 67.06416);
  MYMAP.init('#map', myLatLng, 11);

  $(document).ready(function(e){
        MYMAP.placeMarkers('testasp.asp');

  });
});


var curr_infw;
var MYMAP = {
    map: null,
    bounds: null,
    infowindow:null
}

MYMAP.init = function(selector, latLng, zoom) {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom:zoom,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  }
  this.map = new google.maps.Map($(selector)[0], myOptions);
    this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
}

MYMAP.placeMarkers = function(filename) {
    $.get(filename, function(xml){
        $(xml).find("marker").each(function(){
            var name = $(this).find('name').text();
            var address = $(this).find('address').text();

            // create a new LatLng point for the marker
            var lat = $(this).find('lat').text();
            var lng = $(this).find('lng').text();
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(lng));
            var infowindow = null;

            // extend the bounds to include the new point
            MYMAP.bounds.extend(point);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: point,
                map: MYMAP.map,
                clickable: true,
                icon: 'truck_green.png'

            });

            //var infowindow = null;
            infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var html='<strong>'+name+'</strong.><br />'+address;
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(html);
                infoWindow.open(MYMAP.map, marker);





            });
            MYMAP.map.fitBounds(MYMAP.bounds);
        });
    });
}
```

If somebody help me out I want to refresh it using click event or settimeout function though.

Regards and looking forward to hear it here soon. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but what's this meant to be?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(24.86802, 67.06416);
  MYMAP.init('#map', myLatLng, 11);

  $(document).ready(function(e){
        MYMAP.placeMarkers('testasp.asp');

  });
});
```

Why are you nesting document.ready?   Just do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(24.86802, 67.06416);
    MYMAP.init('#map', myLatLng, 11);
    MYMAP.placeMarkers('testasp.asp');
});
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to initialize map first then markers but as per you corrections do you think it will reload or refresh my markers which's coming from  MYMAP.placeMarkers('testasp.asp'); ??????

Answer (score 0):

For event use

```
google.maps.event.addListener([ mapObject ], 'bounds_changed', function() {
    // [ update code here ]
});
```